# setting innerHTML for all browsers in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load contents of a DIV dynamically in javascript.I used this code

```
 var strHtml="<h3>Test</h3>";
 var div = $("#divPrice");  
 div.innerHTML=strHtml
```

This works in IE. But not in firefox.Whats the alternative of this which works on all browsers ?

Comment: I'm surprised this works in IE... It certainly shouldn't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
var strHtml="<h3>Test</h3>";
$("#divPrice").html(strHtml);
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using jquery, so you can use:

```
 var strHtml="<h3>Test</h3>";
 var div = $("#divPrice");  
 div.html(strHtml);
```

Answer (score 5):

I take it you're using a JavaScript Framework based on `$()`. Looking at your other questions, it looks like you're using jQuery, in which case you can do

```
$("#divPrice").html(strHtml);
```

Just for reference, jQuery's [`html()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) command does the following

```
    jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
        html: function( value ) {
            return value === undefined ?
                (this[0] ?
                    this[0].innerHTML.replace(/ jQuery\d+="(?:\d+|null)"/g, "") :
                    null) :
                this.empty().append( value );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use pure javascript, not jquery.

var div = $("#divPrice");

should be

var div = document.getElementById("divPrice");

Others are fine.